# how to add one list to another list with boja class

Tags: java, spring, arraylist

I have to run two query separately and add in single list like below code,

```
    List<BojaClass> results1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BojaClass> results2 = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql1 = "my query 1";
    String sql2 = "my query 2";
    results1 = jdbcTemplate.query(sql1, new Object[]{1,2}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<BojaClass>(BojaClass.class));
    results2 = jdbcTemplate.query(sql2, new Object[]{1,2}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<BojaClass>(BojaClass.class));
    results1.add((BojaClass) results2);
```

But i am getting exception "**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.myclass.BojaClass**" and results2 values not adding to results1.

where am i doing wrong?

Comment: `results1.addAll(results2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `add` method of the `List` interface which only adds a single element to the list. Use the `addAll` method instead which will add another list.

> **boolean java.util.List.add(E e)**
>
> Appends the specified element to the end of this list (optional
>   operation).
>
> **boolean java.util.List.addAll(Collection c)**
>
> Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the
>   order that they are returned by the specified collection's iterator
>   (optional operation). The behavior of this operation is undefined if
>   the specified collection is modified while the operation is in
>   progress. (Note that this will occur if the specified collection is
>   this list, and it's nonempty.)

Comment: And remove the cast: (BojaClass) results2

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your casting:

```
results1.add((BojaClass) results2);
```

Above should be changed to:

```
results1.add((List<BojaClass>) results2);
```

Hope this fix your issue